# When I paint in vertex paint, and after I switch back to object mode it does not show the paint

Tags: vertex-paint, object-mode

This is the situation here
https://i.gyazo.com/79225d6fd878431834b8b27ea54f59b0.mp4

As you can see when im in vertex paint I can see what I have painted, but once I go into object mode I can no longer see it.

Answer (score 1):

To see the **vertex paint** in Object mode you must switch the display mode to **Texture**.

See the image below showing the vertex showing in Object mode with Texture active:

[image]